# Using git with untracked files

Tags: git

How do you "clean" only the workspace files from a git checkout? I have two branches with:
a) files common to both
b) files unique in each branch
c) untracked files.

I need to get rid of the b) files each time I checkout the other branch, without touching c) the untracked files.

Sorry if it's a simple question. I've see that git clean isn't the answer. Something like 
    rm `git ls-files`?

Comment: As long as your b) files are committed, then `git checkout` should delete them automatically.  Are you trying to switch branches with uncommitted changes in those files?

Comment: Well, that's what isn't making sense. There are no edits or stagings of any files, I'm just checking out back and forth between two branches. I am using checkout -f because I am getting the warning message about overwriting untracked files, AND, after the checkout of branch B, the tracked files unique to branch A are still there in the workspace.

Comment: It's probably the `-f` causing (or at least contributing) to your issues.  Which files are you getting the warning about?

Comment: Yes I think that was it, I had misunderstood the usage of the -f switch. I needed to resolve the workspace inconsistencies between the two branches manually rather than use -f. Ie, some files unique to branch B, left over in the working space of after a checkout -f A, were creating untracked file errors when I tried to check out branch B again.  Seems to be working now that I've got it straight, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)?

```
git stash
git checkout branch_2
...
git checkout branch_1
git stash pop
```

Comment: How does that influence the *untracked* files?

Comment: If the files aren't tracked, it should leave them along. IN his example, (a) and (c) would still be there in branch_2.

Answer (score 0):

As Karl stated in the comments, it should be doing that automatically, but since it's not, you can use `git ls-files | xargs rm` to remove all files (from the working dir) that are in the index (being tracked).  This is kind of a hack, since ideally you would want to figure out why it's not working.